# Entity framework 3033 error when using TPT and table-splitting

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I have the abstract FileSystemItem class that is mapped to a table ("FileSystemItem") and a File class inheriting from it, that is mapped to another table ("File"). 
Then to use lazy-loading I'm adding a FileContents class with binary data to File, and map it to the File table:

```
//The entities:
public abstract class FileSystemItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class File : FileSystemItem
{
    public string FileInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual FileContents Contents { get; set; }
}

public class FileContents
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FileSystemItem> FileSystemItem { get; set; }

    //creating the model with fluent api:
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<FileSystemItem>().ToTable("FileSystemItem");
        modelBuilder.Entity<File>().ToTable("File");
        modelBuilder.Entity<FileContents>().ToTable("File");

        modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.Contents)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

The database is created as expected, but when I try to insert a file it throws this error:

MappingException: 
(20,10) : error 3033: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 20:EntitySets 'FileContents' and 'FileSystemItem' are both mapped to table 'File'. Their primary keys may collide.

What am I doing wrong?